# Are there $CW$-complexes not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ but homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with at most $5$ cells?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there a $CW$-complex $X$ not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ but homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with at most $5$ cells in its cell structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can construct $RP^2$ with three cells, of dimensions $0$, $1$ and $2$. Add to it another $0$-cell and join it to the other old one with a $1$-cell. This is obviously homotopy equivalent to $RP^2$ and has exactly $5$ cells.

It is a projective plane with a hair.

This space is not homeomorphic to the projective plane because it has a point which disconnects it.

**N.B.:** this cannot be done by adding only one cell, because such a space has Euler characteristic different from $1$. In fact, no complex with four cells has the homotopy type of $RP^2$: such a complex must have at least one vertex, of course, it must have at least one $1$-cell, because $H_1(RP^2)\neq0$, and at least one $2$-cell because $H_2(RP^2,\mathbb Z/2)\neq0$, and then whatever dimension a fourth cell might have it will be an obstacle for the Euler characteristic to be $1$, as it should be.

Comment: There are other ways to do this: one could attach a $1$-cell  to $RP^2$ so that its two endpoints get identified with the $0$-cell, getting a loop, and then filling it with a $2$-cell, to get a projective plane with a little disc attached, and this can be done with a $d$-cell and a $(d+1)$-cell for any $d\geq1$.

Comment: A complex with $5$ cells homotopy equivalent to $RP^2$ must have a $0$-cell, a $1$-cell and a $2$-cell, at least, and the other two cells must be of dimensions with different parities. Because the homology of $RP^2$ stops at degree $2$, it is easy to see (considering the cellular complex) that the difference of these dimensions must in fact be $1$. We have seen that all such possibilities actually occur.